# Mac OS: remove old erlang installation

Tags: macos, erlang, rabbitmq

I am using Mac OS Snow leopard and installed erlang from source (R13B04). Now I started using mac ports system to manage software. This port utility installed a newer version of erlang (R14A) runtime during the set up of rabbitmq server. But it looks like when I start rabbitmq it is using the old erlang run time and causing problems.

What is the best way to remove the old erlang installation? Can I just delete those old directories?

Comment: The detailed error follows
erlang version : 5.7.5

WARNING: module gen_server2 not found, so not scanned for boot steps.
WARNING: module rabbit_tests not found, so not scanned for boot steps.
WARNING: module test_sup not found, so not scanned for boot steps.
starting file handle cache server                                     ...done
starting worker pool                                                  ...BOOT ERROR: FAILED
rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{rabbit,failure_during_boot}}}}}"}

Comment: is gen_server2 included in OTP? I think it is not. So the error says your Rabbit built does not see proper paths. I would stick to the sources with OTP and with Rabbit. It gives you better control over versioning middleware.

Comment: I've answered the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747273/how-to-uninstall-erlang-r16b-from-mac-os-x/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall erlang r16b from Mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747273/how-to-uninstall-erlang-r16b-from-mac-os-x)