# How to uninstall erlang r16b from Mac os x

Tags: macos, erlang, uninstallation

I have R16B on OS X (Mountain Lion) and want to uninstall it, to replace with a Homebrew version. Anyone any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have installed it.

I suppose, you've installed it from source, doing `configure && make && make install`.
If so, I'd suggest compiling and installing it once again, now in a 'special' directory. Then, given that list of installed files, uninstall it manually.

So, something like that:

```
ERLTMPDIR=/tmp/myerlang
./configure && make && make DESTDIR=$ERLTMPDIR install
files=`find $ERLTMPDIR -type f`
dirs=`find $ERLTMPDIR -type d`
```

given that list of files and dirs installed you could carefully remove all the files that were installed into your system.

your real files to delete could be obtained by the command:

```
real_files=`find $ERLTMPDIR -type f | sed 's#$ERLTMPDIR#/usr/local#'`
```

(or change `/usr/local` to some other directory, if you specified it manually in your previos erlang installation)

I'm not absolutely sure, but it seems that erlang doesn't patch any environment or init.d files.